# Entity Framework 6 Code First and MySql DateTime precision?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

I'm using **EF 6** with the latest **MySql .Net Connector** in **Code First** and I can't find how to set my DateTime column precision to 6, it always seems to be 0 (no milliseconds)!

I tried:

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)).Configure(p => p.HasPrecision(6));
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<my_table>()
                .Property(e => e.my_datetime)
                .HasPrecision(6);
```

But it seems to be ignored, I've traced `context.Database.Log` and I can see my date formatted without precision: `@gp2: '2015-10-26 15:59:06' (Type = DateTime, IsNullable = false)`

I made a test project but this time, using the **EF Designer** and it work correctly :S In the edmx file I can see the precision defined `<Property Name="my_datetime" Type="datetime" Precision="6" />` and when I add an object to the database, my precision is correctly set with 6 fractional seconds precision.

Comment: do you use db migration? cause I might have a workaround

Comment: No but it may be useful for someone else, what's your workaround?

Comment: I'm no longer able to reproduce your problem. Seems like HasPrecision(6) works now. Maybe it was a bug in the MySQL EF connector that has since been fixed? (Leaving this note here, so others know to try your solution.)

Comment: @JamieF I'm not working on that project anymore so I can't test it, thanks for the information